# Better function for collections

Tags: collections, clojure, bubble-sort

Answering a question in SO, I stumbled into this problem:

```
(def x [7 4 8 9 10 54 55 2 23 30 12 5])

(defn insert-x 
  ([sorted-coll x] 
   (insert-x sorted-coll x 
     (if (= (type sorted-coll) clojure.lang.PersistentVector) [] '())))

  ([sorted-coll x acc]
  (let [is-vector  (= (type sorted-coll) clojure.lang.PersistentVector)
        format-it  #(into (if is-vector [] '()) %)
        compare   (if is-vector < >)]
    (cond 
      (empty? sorted-coll) (format-it (cons x acc))

      (compare (peek sorted-coll) x) 
      (format-it (concat 
                   ((if is-vector identity reverse) sorted-coll) 
                   (conj acc x)))

      :else (recur (pop sorted-coll) x (cons (peek sorted-coll) acc))))))

(defn bubble-sort [coll]
  "Insert x into a sorted collection"
  (reduce insert-x [] coll))

(bubble-sort x)
;; => [2 4 5 7 8 9 10 12 23 30 54 55]
```

The code does what it should.

However, `insert-x` is not so elegant.
How to write `insert-x` in a way that it is valid for all collections?
So that it is simpler/more elegant?
vectors should return vectors, lists should return lists etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess you're overthinking it.

you have two tasks:

1. insert item at the proper position inside a sorted collection
2. return vector for input vector and list for input list

first of all, i would rewrite the `insert-x` like this for example:

```
(defn insert-x [sorted-coll x]
  (let [[l r] (split-with #(<= % x) sorted-coll)]
    `(~@l ~x ~@r)))
```

notice, it does more or less the same that your variant does: taking values until the desired positions, and then concatenating left and right parts with `x` between them. notice also, it always produces properly sorted list, independent from the input type.

```
user> (insert-x [1 3 5 7 9] 10)
;;=> (1 3 5 7 9 10)

user> (insert-x [1 3 5 7 9] 0)
;;=> (0 1 3 5 7 9)

user> (insert-x [1 3 5 7 9] 4)
;;=> (1 3 4 5 7 9)
```

so, the next thing you need, is just to reduce input and return the properly typed result:

```
(defn my-sort [coll]
  (let [sorted (reduce insert-x () coll)]
    (if (vector? coll)
      (vec sorted)
      sorted)))

user> (my-sort '(0 3 1 4 2 5 10 7))
;;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 7 10)

user> (my-sort [0 3 1 4 2 5 10 7])
;;=> [0 1 2 3 4 5 7 10]

user> (my-sort ())
;;=> ()

user> (my-sort [])
;;=> []
```

Comment: This is likely to cause a stack overflow for moderately sized collections, `(my-sort (shuffle (range 1000)))`, due to stacking of lazy `concat` and lazy `split-with`.

Comment: @A.Webb . Sure, but since it seems to be the education-only task (who would really use this in production?) that will do. Otherwise ```(doall `(~@l ~x ~@r))``` solves this.

Comment: @leetwinski how would you approach it in production? (built-in sort functions?)

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim it essentially depends on your task and input size. Generally, built-in `sort` is good enough, so you should consider optimizing it iff it is necessary. You could also take a look at sorted-sets, in in case you need to keep your changing data sorted, which is better then resorting it every time it changes. But again, we can't reason about it unless we have any task specific information

Answer (score 5):

What you need is to have `insert-x` working on regular list (ie. `'()` or nil) and rewriting `bubble-sort` to create the same type as input using `empty` function.

`empty` returns empty collection of the same type:

```clj
(class (empty [1 2]))
;; => clojure.lang.PersistentVector
(class (empty #{1 2}))
;; => clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet
(class (empty '(1 2)))
;; => clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList
```

Your `bubble-sort` can look this way:

```clj
(defn bubble-sort [coll]
  "Insert x into a sorted collection"
  (into (empty coll) (reduce insert-x nil coll)))
```

This way you can get rid of all type checks inside `insert-x`

Comment: @generateme - however this `(into (emtpy coll) ...)` construct must take place in the level of `insert-x` and not later. Because otherwise `reduce` complains (when e.g. vector input's inbetween result is a list).

Comment: ah no I realized - it doesn't solve the `conj`/`cons` problem of vectors and lists and their order ... is there a nice solution for them?

Comment: Because in lists I had to `reverse` but with vectors not etc. That is why `insert-x` became so complicated. and I was asking myself, whether there is a more unified solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you both!

I took both of your answers and generated this solution:

```
(defn insert-x [sq x]
  (apply concat (interleave (split-with #(<= % x) sq) [[x] []])))

(defn bubble-sort [sq]
  ((if (vector? sq) vec identity)
   (reduce insert-x () sq)))
```

Test:

```
user=> (bubble-sort '(0 2 8 3 9 7))
(0 2 3 7 8 9)
user=> (bubble-sort [0 2 8 3 9 7])
[0 2 3 7 8 9]
```

Or probably even better readable:

```
(defn insert [q x]
  (let [[l r] (split-with #(< % x) sq)] 
    (concat l [x] r)))

(defn bubble-sort [sq]
  ((if (vector? sq) vec identity) 
   (reduce insert () sq)))
```

Or:

```
(defn insert [sq x]
  (let [[l r] (split-with #(< % x) sq)] 
    `(~@l ~x ~@r)))

(defn intoo [x sq] ;; direction neutral `into`
  (into x (into x sq))) 

(defn bubble-sort [sq]
  (intoo (empty sq) (reduce insert () sq)))
```

`intoo` is needed because of

```
(into () '(1 2 3)) ;;=> '(3 2 1)
(into () [1 2 3])  ;;=> '(3 2 1)
(into [] '(1 2 3)) ;;=> [1 2 3]
(into [] [1 2 3])  ;;=> [1 2 3]
# `into` uses `conj` underneath!
```

Apply two times successively `into` fixes this:

```
(into () (into () '(1 2 3))) ;; '(1 2 3)
(into () (into () [1 2 3]))  ;; '(1 2 3)
(into [] (into [] '(1 2 3))) ;; [1 2 3]
(into [] (into [] [1 2 3]))  ;; [1 2 3]
```

Thus `intoo` is kind of a direction neutral version of `into`.

Actually, the most performance efficient version of `intoo` might be:

```
(defmacro intoo [x sq]
  (if (vector? x)
      `(into ~x ~sq)
      `(reverse (into ~x ~sq))))

;; user=> (intoo () '(1 2 3))
;; (1 2 3)
;; user=> (intoo () [1 2 3])
;; (1 2 3)
;; user=> (intoo [] [1 2 3])
;; [1 2 3]
;; user=> (intoo [] '(1 2 3))
;; [1 2 3]

;; or as a function:
(defn intoo [x & args]
  (if (vector? x)
      (apply into x args)
      (reverse (apply into x args))))
```